# Проблемы с настройкой проксификации

Tags: прокси, javascript

Добрый вечер! Есть скрипт проксификации. Ставлю его на сайт, прописываю урл отображаемого сайта

Но кроме белого экрана ничего не загружается! Как можно решить проблему и какие исходные данные нужны, чтобы вы смогли определить проблему?

---

1 https://yadi.sk/d/zN9gc_oBWMgNB Там вписан уже сайт, который должен отображаться
2 Домен Бет-вин.рф
3 Да заливаю на хостинг, добавлется index.php, папка cache (с проставленными праами записи), и замена .htaccess

Comment: Ну для начала:
1. Что за скрипт (ссылочку), это же либа?
2. К чему прикручиваете? 
3. Он точно присутствует на странице, может 404 или другие ошибки возникают, в дебагере не проверяли?

Comment: 1. https://yadi.sk/d/zN9gc_oBWMgNB Там вписан уже сайт, который должен отображаться
2. Домен Бет-вин.рф
3. Да заливаю на хостинг, добавлется index.php, папка cache (с проставленными праами записи), и замена .htaccess